# Move posts if taxonomy is 'category'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query that moves all my matching slugs on 'Posts' into a custom post type:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
    SET p.post_type =  'recipe'
    WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND x.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND t.slug = 'cocktails'
    OR t.slug = 'breakfast'
    OR t.slug = 'cookies-recipes'
    OR t.slug = 'desserts'
    OR t.slug = 'main-course'
    OR t.slug = 'sides'
    OR t.slug = 'soups'
    OR t.slug = 'starters'
```

The problem is, the `AND x.taxonomy='category'` is not working for me, it moves all the slugs associated with both 'category' and 'post_tag', how can I make it where it looks for the 'category' only and moves just that over?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this...

```
UPDATE wp_posts p 
  JOIN wp_term_relationships r 
    ON r.object_id = p.ID
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x 
    ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
  JOIN wp_terms t 
    ON t.term_id = x.term_id
   SET p.post_type = 'recipe'
 WHERE p.post_type = 'post' 
   AND x.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND t.slug IN('cocktails',
                 'breakfast',
                 'cookies-recipes',
                 'desserts',
                 'main-course',
                 'sides',
                 'soups',
                 'starters')
```

For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)